# C++, async, Access violation error, very simple code but very strange error

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, c++14

When i run this simple code, i get error "Access violation executing location 0x00F3F694".
Very strange thing is that if I add or remove any arguments to the function func, then code runs without errors.
I can't understand what is the problem. Thank you in advance if anyone can help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<future>

using namespace std;

void func
(
    double *x,
    double *g,
    int begin,
    int end,
    int m
)
{
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    future<void> future = async(func, nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0, 0);
    future.get();
    cout << "DONE" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have undefined behavior elswhere. However I cannot reproduce that, but get a bunch of compiler warnings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc51c37eee70898c

Comment: Those warnings are just because im not using variables in func for anything (i removed all not relevant code to localize the problem). Undefined behavior cant be elsewhere because I even copied only this small code to the new project in other computer but it has same problem. I'm using visual studio on windows

Comment: The behavior you describe can't be reproduced though.

Comment: As i said i reproduced error on another computer. Maybe problem is in visual studios implementation? someone with visual studio 2017 should try to reproduce it

Comment: I compiled and ran this in VS 2017 (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.12.25830.2 for x86) and it runs with no errors.  (Maybe you have something strange in "stdafx.h"?  I excluded that line since it is unnecessary.)

Comment: I removed "stdafx.h" include too, but still same error, and again, if i change function parameters(add one more integer for example) it works.